# Prototype 1.7: Is there a way to serialize elements outside of form?

Tags: prototypejs

In Prototype, is there a way to serialize all 'input' elements on the page after looking up using `$$`? I have to work with some pages that don't have any forms or some elements are outside of form hence cannot use Form.serialize or Form.serializeElements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can use `Form.serialzeElements()` outside of a form you just need to pass it a list of elements.

For example

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="a" id="a" value="12345" />
<input type="text" name="b" id="b" value="6789" />
```

Javascript

```
Form.serializeElements($$('input'))
```

returns

```
a=12345&b=6789
```

try it out in this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/av5Kj/